# How do I suggest a 1-character edit?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

Every once in a while I encounter an answer which claims to be Python. However, most Python code is specific to either Python 2 or Python 3.

Often the answer starts with

## Python

Which should be fixed to either

## Python 2

or

## Python 3

However, this edit is only one character. I need six to make an edit. If there's more to be changed, I'll do it. But often there's nothing wrong with the rest of the answer.

What should I do when encountering such answers?

Comment: Alternatively: "Python (2.7.x)" ;)

Comment: @dacapoaria Wouldn't such edits be frowned upon? Adding more characters than necessary just to have the required amount of characters reminds me of old forum restrictions. If it's not frowned upon it would solve the immediate problem (or it would be grounds for a new meta Q).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I thought I might as well turn my comment into an answer:

If you really can't find enough to improve to add more than the two bytes for the space and the version number, **just leave a comment**. The author of the post as well as high-rep users don't have this 6-character limitation, and someone will likely take care of it.

Answer (score -3):

I read this tip on the StackOverflow meta recently but I can't find the post. You could add the comment to the post:

```
<!-- workaround for 6 character edit limit -->
```

and make the 1-2 character change. Then a higher rep user will see it in the review and can take the comment out with the improve the edit option.

Comment: Not a fan of cheating the Stack Exchange system. I prefer the leave a comment method.

Comment: This is frustrating for people in reviews. It may not be a big issue on a small site like this, so I'm not downvoting this, but on a site like StackOverflow having to improve too many reviews from a user will likely get their reviews rejected and a mod warning.